# Restricting Input in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am creating a custom control that when invoked in the XAML can be set to only allow certain types of inputs:

`<lib:CustomControl RestrictTo="UnsignedIntegersOnly" ... ></CustomControl>`

Where the UnsignedIntegersOnly is part of an Enum containing the set of allowed restrictions.

If the user inputs something that is not allowed, the control will throw a validation error and not allow him to continue to the next form/page/etc.

My vision for implementing this, was to, in the underlying TextBox that makes up this control, bind its text field to a validation rule which will be passed as an input the RestrictTo value that was specified in the CustomControl XAML declaration. Then in that ValidationRule class, handle the RestrictTo specific validation and return whether the validation was successful or not.

This is where I am not quite sure how to proceed. Is it even possible to pass arguments to the ValidationRule in such a seemingly dynamic manner? I am setting a property, RestrictTo, of my control and then passing that to its validation.

If it is possible, how would it be done? What sort of binding or resource linking should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in using a MaskedTextBox control, it will restrict what the user can input in the TextBox.

As there's no official control from Microsoft for WPF I would suggest the following from Xceed :

[MaskedTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) (it's free to use :-)

Here you have the syntax of the mask :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="0000"></xctk:MaskedTextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you have Visual Studio 2012 you can easily get this package through NuGet :

(right-click on your project )

[image]

Note : on my answer to your previous question, I extensively used validation rules in the link I posted but I'd say that if there are some times where you can avoid it through the means of a well-crafted component/control, then it's wise to do so. As @Barn pointed out on your previous question, a generic validation rule might be a hard thing to do and somewhat questionable as you'll have to handle all the types in it, IMO it's a little counter-intuitive as validators and converters are generally specific against being generalist; you're likely to waste more time on it than it's worth and it will be probably less re-usable than you think it could be. (source : my experience)

Comment: My biggest issue is that I am following a very strict separation of concerns architecture. I do not want to have any validation logic in the code-behind of the control. I want it to seamlessly integrate through bindings. In my experience, maintaining a very high level of modularity and separation makes it really easy to maintain code. A lot of the times I have to modify code that is very, very coupled and it takes forever to make small changes.

I like that Masked TextBox but I unfortunately cannot use any third party packages like this one (policy).

Comment: Regarding fields, they are either a string or a number therefore you should have one validation rule per type and per control. If it's more complex than that, maybe you can create multiple controls instead of one. You could restrict the user by using a ListBox or ComboBox with only valid values instead. Did you try the pattern I explained in my answer at  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/is-there-an-effective-way-for-creating-complex-forms ? Also, I'd suggest you to edit your question and post more details and more code, a concrete case of where you're stuck for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should get you started. It is a user control and not a custom control. I recomend you get your code working as a user control first and then convert it to a custom control. Bind Valid property to some property in your viewmodel that controls user workflow.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication.ValidatingControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Name="_textBox" TextChanged="OnTextChanged" Background="LightGray" Width="200"/>
        <TextBlock Name="_messageText" Foreground="Red" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class ValidatingControl : UserControl
    {
        public ValidatingControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public enum Restrictions
        {
            UnsignedIntegersOnly,
            SmallIntegersOnly        
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RestrictToProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RestrictTo", typeof(Restrictions), typeof(ValidatingControl), new PropertyMetadata(Restrictions.UnsignedIntegersOnly));

        public Restrictions RestrictTo
        {
            get { return (Restrictions)GetValue(RestrictToProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RestrictToProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool Valid
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ValidProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValidProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Valid", typeof(bool), typeof(ValidatingControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ValidateText(RestrictTo, _textBox.Text);
        }

        private void ValidateText(Restrictions restrictTo, string text)
        {
            // validate text, update _messageText, update Valid 
        }
    }
}
```